# Why can't I query Delta Tables using Athena Version 3

Tags: dataframe, amazon-s3, aws-glue, amazon-athena, delta-lake

I am writing Delta Lake tables to AWS S3 and I am attempting to use Amazon Athena to query these Delta Tables (it works fine when I save them as Parquet).

The tables are being saved in my AWS Glue Catalog under "database"."tablename", but all of the Delta Tables have the location of `"s3://<path-in-s3>-__PLACEHOLDER__"` - I'm not sure what causes the PLACEHOLDER part (or if it's even relevant, but the parquet tables don't have it and work fine).

When I try to query the results in Athena, I just get the error "DELTA_LAKE_INVALID_SCHEMA"

Notes

- I am using Athena Engine Version 3
- My Athena query is just `SELECT * from database.table`
- To save the Delta Lake table into S3 I am doing

```
df.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").option(
    "overwriteSchema", "true"
).option('table_type', 'DELTA').option('has_encrypted_data', True).save(target_loc)

DeltaTable.createIfNotExists(spark).location(target_loc).property(
        "has_encrypted_data", "true"
).property('table_type', 'DELTA').tableName(target_table).addColumns(df.schema).execute()
```

Any idea about what I could be doing wrong with either how I'm saving the delta tables / how I'm querying them in Athena?

Comment: Might help: [Querying Delta Lake tables - Amazon Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/delta-lake-tables.html)

Comment: Presumably the "invalid" schema (name) would actually be in your `target_table` variable (and have nothing to do with the s3 location). Does that variable show a schema you can find in your AwsDataCatalog (not saying everything will work if you fix that - I haven't tried some of the options you're using).

Comment: Were you able to solve the issue ? I'm facing the same issue although when I run the query via Athena UI its working. My query is failing if I'm making the query via AWS GO SDK.